# What UserAgent is program sending

Tags: trace, user-agent

I want to trace the http requests a program on my computer is making, actually what I really want it to find what it is setting as the useragent. How do I do this, a solution for Windows or OSX would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool to use is [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org)

Comment: Just trying Wireshark as im currenlty on a Mac (and Fiddler is WIndows only), but a bit daunting not managing to get anything working yet

Answer (score 0):

If you use firefox, there is the User Agent Switcher extension:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark was mentioned, but I find [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/version.asp) better fit for the task. It presents captured data more accessible than Wireshark.